# React Native Camera shows blank screen with loading spinner

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-camera, expo-permissions

I am working in react native with expo and I am trying to implement react native camera. However, when I implement it into my own code and even use [this](https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/rncamera) usage code, it shows a blank screen with a loading icon and gives the warning

> Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity.

I use expo permissions and get permission for both camera and audio earlier in the app. This issue happens on both android and IOS.

Here is my configuration:

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.59.8

Comment: I have also run react-native link react-native-camera

Comment: have you taken a look at its documentation on expo usage [here](https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/expo_usage)?

Comment: Yes, that is how I switched from expo camera to react-native camera but it still shows the blank screen and gives the warning. I am currently using expo camera but I need to use codec to force encode in H264 which is why I am switching to react-native camera. Thanks for your response and any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Luke20w I'm looking forward for a solution. Do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo, you won't be able to use native modules like react-native-camera. Instead, you can use expo sdk, they have an expo-camera that you can use.
Here is the link: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/camera/

Comment: you have to use react-native-cli, to use native modules in your project.

Comment: Yes I am using expo camera now but there is no way to set encoding to H264

Comment: you can get image data in base64

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I am recording video not taking pictures.

Comment: you can use expo-eject, to use native modules

Comment: Thanks, however, I would love to keep using Expo if at all possible. I test on my phone through Expo Client and the upload process to the App Store and Google Play Store is very streamlined. Is there any way within Expo to force record with H264 encoding?

Comment: I think you have to wait for this feature to be added to the sdk. You can get more information here: https://forums.expo.io/